# How do I check if 'Allow access requests' is checked using CSOM in Sharepoint Team site

Tags: c#, sharepoint, office365, csom

We have bunch of Sharepoint sites deployed into production. I was given a task to provide a report on whether the 'Allow access requests' (located in the 'Access Requests Console') is checked or not

I do know how to check it or uncheck it programmatically (using the DisableRequestAccess() or EnableRequestAccess() methods of siteContext.Web object)

However, I can't figure out how to find out if the 'Allow access requests' is checked or not

What is the right boolean value of the siteContext.Web object that would tell me if the 'Allow access requests' is checked or not.

Thank you everyone in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has two situations:

1. Use default access requests. It should be the property `Web.UseAccessRequestDefault`
2. Use email to reveive access requests. It would be the property `Web.RequestAccessEmail`

Comment: Thank you very much. I initially couldn't find the UseAccessRequestDefault property, but after I updated mu CSOM through nuget to a latest stable, it became available